# bind popup to dynamic list of markers in Leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet

When I bind a popup to a single marker, it works fine:

```
const ugh = L.marker([60.6157376, 10.27716])
  .addTo(this.leafleftMap)
  .bindPopup("I work")
```

and when I add markers to a map from an API call it works fine too:

```
const markers = new L.FeatureGroup()
displayedStories.forEach((marker, i) => {
  let m = L.marker(marker.coords)
  markers.addLayer(m)
})
```

but I can't bind popups to each marker when going over a list:

```
const markers = new L.FeatureGroup()
displayedStories.forEach((marker, i) => {
  const m = L.marker(marker.coords)
    .addTo(this.leafleftMap)
    .bindPopup("I don't work")
  markers.addLayer(m)
})
```

and I've also tried LayerGroups, following an example I found in [the docs](http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/):

```
const markers = displayedStories.map(story => L.marker(story.coords)
  .bindPopup("I don't work"))
const storyMarkers = L.layerGroup(markers)
```

In the above two examples, the markers still appear on the map, but no popups open when I click on them.

My guess is that it has to do with reassigning the `m` constant to each item in the list, though I may be wrong.

Comment: `m` is not being reassigned; you can't reassign a `const`. Each iteration of the `forEach` is a separate function call, so they're all different `m`s.

Answer (score 1):

Your two examples should work without issue:

```js
var map = L.map('map');

var displayedStories = [{
  coords: [60.6157376, 10.27716]
}, {
  coords: [61.6157376, 10.27716]
}, {
  coords: [62.6157376, 10.27716]
}];
var displayedStories2 = [{
  coords: [60.6157376, 11.27716]
}, {
  coords: [61.6157376, 11.27716]
}, {
  coords: [62.6157376, 11.27716]
}];

const markers = new L.FeatureGroup().addTo(map);
displayedStories.forEach((marker, i) => {
  const m = L.marker(marker.coords)
    .addTo(map)
    .bindPopup("I don't work")
  markers.addLayer(m)
});

const markers2 = displayedStories2.map(story => L.marker(story.coords)
  .bindPopup("I don't work2"))
const storyMarkers = L.layerGroup(markers2).addTo(map);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

map.fitBounds(markers.getBounds().pad(.2));
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha512-IkGU/uDhB9u9F8k+2OsA6XXoowIhOuQL1NTgNZHY1nkURnqEGlDZq3GsfmdJdKFe1k1zOc6YU2K7qY+hF9AodA==" crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 200px"></div>
```

Comment: You're right. The issue is coming from trying to get the map to interact with Vue